# concrete5 create password hash that is comparable to stored value

Tags: php, hash, passwords, concrete5

I'm building a front-end user profile section, where the user can change his login password.

To be on the safe side, I want the user to enter first his current password before he can enter a new one.

But I can't figure out how to encrypt the password the way it can be checked against the value in the database. With my approach I always get a different string generated with the same input value.

Do you have any idea?

Here is what I'm trying right now:

```
$oldPassword = $ui->getUserPassword();
echo"<pre>";    var_dump($oldPassword);   echo"</pre>";

$pw = User::getUserPasswordHasher();
//echo"<pre>";    var_dump($pw);   echo"</pre>";

$controlPassword = User::getUserPasswordHasher()->HashPassword('stern3');
echo"<pre>";    var_dump($controlPassword);   echo"</pre>";
```

I'm using concrete5 Version 5.6.3.3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How i can see concrete5 use external library `Hautelook\Phpass\PasswordHash` and this class has method `CheckPassword`:

https://github.com/hautelook/phpass/blob/f0217d804225822f9bdb0d392839029b0fcb0914/src/Hautelook/Phpass/PasswordHash.php#L305-L313

So you must get user from DB and run this method to compare password hashes.

I hope it will help